# Detect search index Amazon product API Item Search - Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, search, amazon-product-api

I'm using amazon product API, when I call the itemSearch method

```
client.itemSearch({
    searchIndex: 'All',
    itemPage : page,
    keywords: keywords,
    availability:'Available',
    domain: 'webservices.amazon.it',
    responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Offers,Images'
  }
```

It always searches in the main category. Example: if I search "iphone" on Amazon I get these results which are equal to the result of my API call

[image: search on the main category]

But if I search "iphone 6" amazon automatically detects it has to search in "Elettronica: cellulari e accessori" (in English "Electronics smartphones and accessories").

[image]

How can I change the parameters of the API call to auto detect the right category?

Comment: You can use autocomplete response from amazon , it has node / category value that you can use to define or give category suggestion for your user. 

Here is the link example.

https://completion.amazon.co.uk/search/complete?method=completion&mkt=35691&r=WGXEV7YCVZDD2CKCA2YT&s=261-0683645-9393243&c=&p=Gateway&l=it_IT&sv=desktop&client=amazon-search-ui&x=String&search-alias=aps&q=iphone 6